# Custom Notification in Oracle Fusion

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-integration-cloud

i wanted to know if there is anyway to create custom Notification / bell alerts on Oracle fusion that can be triggered via Oracle OIC . Basically i want to send notification from Oracle OIC to Oracle fusion. A normal bell notification is what I'm looking for. Or can we create a notification in fusion and call it via ess Job scheduler ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom bell notification on Fusion by calling this REST API URL -

POST https://hostname/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/atkPopupItems

Sample Payload -

```
{
  "UserGUID" : "EBFD93D0C1C07379E040548C2C0410A0",
  "MessageSummary" : "Custom Message Text",
  "Status" : "UNREAD"
}
```

Documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/22a/farca/op-fscmrestapi-resources-11.13.18.05-atkpopupitems-post.html

---

Please note that you'll need the GUID of the user to which you're going to be sending the notification.

You can query for it by the following call:

GET https://hostname/hcmRestApi/scim/Users?filter=userName eq "jane.doe"

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/22a/farca/op-hcmrestapi-scim-users-get.html